# Semi-bold \mathbf

Tags: fonts

Is there a way to obtain semi-bold version of the standard `\mathbf` command?

I'm using the `kpfonts` package which somewhat reduces the weight in `\mathbf` but I'd still like to lighten it a bit. Is there a command for doing so?

Comment: Do you mind posting a minimal example what shows this effect, I see no change in the weight of say `x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `rmx` option that provides a semi-bold weight.

Here's the output with just `\usepackage{kpfonts}`

[image]

Here's how to get semi-bold:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[rmx]{kpfonts}
\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{sb}

\makeatletter
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{OT1}{jkpx}{sb}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathbf}{bold}{OT1}{jkpx}{b}{n}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

abc\textbf{abc}abc$\mathrm{a}\mathbf{b}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Thank you egreg! One last thing, is there an easy way to have both versions of boldness available in the same document?

Comment: Sorry egreg. Maybe there is something I am doing wrong, but now it seems that the command \boldmath is no longer having any effect.

Comment: @suitangi Not in my test. Maybe it needs some adjustment. That's another question altogether, though. Please be specific about your needs and issues.

Comment: Sure @egreg, I'll look more closely to see what happens. Thank you again.